# Creating class template diagram in VS2010 Ultimate

Tags: visual-studio-2010, uml

Is there an option in VS2010 Ultimate in UML tools to create class diagram which would indicate that this class is a template (with types and how many of them) in the way class template diagram according to UML 2.0 looks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Sorry I can't post a functioning link here, but take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd409416.aspx#Templates